# Gradually rising or falling numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I'm looking for a number series I can use for gradually rising or falling numbers. The number series should not be linear and should converge to a number at some point.

$\sqrt[N]{N}$ where $N > 3$; $N \in \mathbb{Z}$. (This series gradually falls)

Its inverse is then used for the opposite

I've verified for $N$ for the set $[4,5,\ldots,9]$

Do you know about other options? Other things I should consider?

They don't need to be inverses.

Comment: $a + 1/N$ decreases to $a$; $a + 1/\log N$ decreases to $a$ more gradually; $a + 1/\log\log N$ even more gradually; and so on.

Comment: Ill graph it to see what it looks like. I'm interested is  as many options as possible and they don't need to be inverses. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $e^{-kn}$ for a falling series and $1-e^{-kn}$ for rising.  Or $\frac 1{1+n}$ for falling and $\frac n{n+1}$ for rising.  There are *lots* of possibilities-better definition is needed.

Comment: Ill graph it to see what it looks like. I'm interested is  as many options as possible and they don't need to be inverses. Thanks for the help.

Comment: i ended up deciding to use something similar to this       http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20934/how-to-create-adjustable-formula-for-rpg-level-up-requirements